# Open Sybase Sql Anywhere 9 .db file without DBA PASSWORD of 3rd party

Tags: sybase-asa

I'm Beginner in Sybase Sql Anywhere.

I have a "coop_db.db" file from the 2nd Party.

I want to open this file but i dont have a **UserID** and **Password** from the 3rd Party. I already tried the default authentication

```
UserID:"dba" and Password:"sql"
```

but it won't work.

Can anyone help me figure it out what's the DBA PASSWORD to this file.? Thanks, deeply appreciate your help :D.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to force your way into a SQL Anywhere database if you don't know the password. I looked into this in the past and there is no backdoor, nor a forced-reset procedure like ASE has.